# Django: Get a queryset of ForeignKey elements from another queryset

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a Foo class. Given a queryset of `Foo`, how can I retrieve the queryset of Users?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("users.User", related_name="foos")
    ...


foo_objects = Foo.objects.all()
```

One method I've seen is:

```
users = Users.objects.filter(id__in=list(foo_objects.values_list("user_id", flat=True))
```

Is there any way to get the list of all users in the `foo_objects` queryset without this list conversion?

```
users = User.objects.filter(user_id__in=foo_objects.values("user_id"))
```

If the second option works– does anyone have any experience re: which method works better with postgresql? I've heard nested queries (the second option) doesn't work great on some databases.

Comment: On MySQL the first one will typically work faster, since MySQL (often) does not optimize constant subqueries. For PostgreSQL, It might be better to use the latter as far as I know. But you might want to run some benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

The second option does appear to be an order of magnitude faster on postgres:

```
>>> do_nested_lookup() <- Option 2
Total execution time: 0.0005328655242919922 seconds
>>> do_flat_lookup() <- Option 1
Total execution time: 0.0017600059509277344 seconds
```